# Context in EnableListAdapter

Tags: android, this, android-context

I have created an `ExpandableListAdapter` class and I need to send it the context from the activity that is accessing it.

**MyActivity.class:**

```
MenuExpandableListAdapter.useInstanceContext(getApplicationContext());
```

**MyExpandableListAdapter.class:**

```
static Context context;
public static void useInstanceContext(Context applicationContext) {
    context = applicationContext;
}
```

The above code works, but this also works:

```
MenuExpandableListAdapter.useInstanceContext(this.getApplicationContext());
```

What's the difference? Is this a good way to pass context? I'm still trying to fully understand context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Context is necessary in order to get access to the resources and some other things. So, both - application and activity contexts work. But a good practice is tight to the smallest thing, which works, which is activity in your case. So, I would suggest new way for you:

```
MenuExpandableListAdapter.useInstanceContext(this);
```

Also, in your example, there is no difference between the calls. `this` is just the reference to the current object.

Answer (score 1):

`this` refers to the object that is currently executing code, if the method is declared in the same class, and is not static, it is the same to call:

```
getApplicationContext()
```

and

```
this.getApplicationContext()
```

(The same applies to class members)

Answer (score 0):

```
MenuExpandableListAdapter.useInstanceContext(getApplicationContext());
```

The getApplicationContext() method will called by using  calling/current object implicitly.

in second  you are giving calling/current object explicitly because this is special object that is always refer to calling object.

i suggest you to use this

```
MenuExpandableListAdapter.useInstanceContext(this.getApplicationContext());
```

because as per my reading it's good practice.